# Listeners in Apache Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

I'm new to Apache Jmeter here.

While reading user manual documents of Jmeter, I see this:

> View Results Tree MUST NOT BE USED during load test as it consumes a lot of resources (memory and CPU). Use it only for either functional testing or during Test Plan debugging and Validation.

The above statement is taken from this document, just under the View Results Tree section
 **http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Save_Responses_to_a_file**

I want to ask how I can use Listeners that is "MUST NOT BE USED during load test..."?

in GUI mode, Jmeter Apache.

Any suggest is appreciated.

Comment: I think the workding "MUST NOT" is too strong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**GUI mode is only for creating & debugging your test**. So, You can use any listeners you want which will help you to debug your test. Once your test is created/updated, remove/disable those listeners. When you actually do the loadtest with Jmeter, You need to run your test in Non-GUI mode. This site has really good information on using JMeter.

http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips

When you run in non-gui mode, you pass the argument for the location where the result file should be created. Later you can import the result file in JMeter for analysis.

Comment: It is really helpful. Please give me a moment before checking this post as the best answer :D